# Ubuntu - Laravel 5.6 - Unable to load ffprobe (using php-ffmpeg)

Tags: php, ubuntu, ffmpeg, laravel-5.6

I have ffmpeg and ffprobe installed on my ubuntu system (can access it via command line)

ffmpeg and ffprobe are located in /usr/bin/

I installed these via composer

```
"php-ffmpeg/binary-driver": "dev-master",
"php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "^0.11.1",
```

I've done: 
    use FFMpeg;

```
// in index() function//

$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/usr/bin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffprobe'
]);
```

and still get

> FFMpeg \ Exception \ ExecutableNotFoundException
>
> Unable to load FFProbe

I have looked at about 30 forums for this and no luck, some direction would be helpful

**UPDATE**
I tried `chmod +x /usr/bin/ffprobe`

Then restarted, did nothing.

I then tried:

`sudo chgrp www-data /usr/bin/ffprobe
sudo chmod g+x      /usr/bin/ffprobe`

Then restarted, did nothing.

**UPDATE**
I forgot to mention that I am running php-fpm + nginx in docker.I added pbmedia wrapper for php-ffmpeg and If I run the laravel project without docker (php artisan serve) it works fine.

The issue now is that I need to reference the /usr/bin/ffprobe directory from within docker

Comment: Are the binaries executeable? (Set it with `chmod +x /usr/bin/ffprobe`)

Comment: `The issue now is that I need to reference the /usr/bin/ffprobe directory from within docker` - you mean to say `/usr/bin/ffprobe` is actually installed on the host but is not present in the docker images/container?

Answer (score 0):

You mention

> ffmpeg and ffprobe are located in /usr/bin/

but later your code if referring to them in `/usr/local/bin/`

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe'
]);
```

That's one thing to check.

The other is to ensure that the binaries have the executable bit set for the right user that php runs as .. under ubuntu this user may be the `www-data`  (if you're unsure have your php script emit the output of `whoami` or `id -un`, etc).

```
sudo chgrp www-data /usr/bin/ffprobe
sudo chmod g+x      /usr/bin/ffprobe
```

Comment: Please relook at the post. I edited it before an answer came through. It's /usr/bin with no local. That's where they are stored

Comment: I'll try the other thing you menention tomorrow and will let you know